# NLTK cannot import a specific corpus (pl196x)

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, corpus

My NLTK mysteriously refuses to import corpus pl196x (included in the standard package of corpora). When I do `from nltk.corpus import brown` everything goes smooth, but with `from nltk.corpus import pl196x`, it is always

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "<input>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: cannot import name 'pl196x' from 'nltk.corpus' (C:\my\path\to\__init__.py)`

and it already happened on multiple PCs and OSs.

1. I did nltk.download() all corpora, they show as downloaded
2. The files are there

[image: nltk data folder]

3. I checked the `nltk.data.path` and it does contain `'C:\\nltk_data'`

I have no idea what is wrong - currently the only possible explanation for me is that the corpus was somehow discontinued. Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate way to import `pl196x` corpus is using:

```
from nltk.corpus.reader import pl196x
```

This is hinted by the [documentation of the module](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/pl196x.html).

Comment: Unbelievable. Thank you, I would never expect it to load in such non-standard way since it is listed for download just like the other corpora. Still, I don't understand the difference caused by this - should I still have access to all the corpus methods or is pl196x somehow restricted since it is loaded as a corpus reader?

Comment: I am not sure. You would have to compare the implementation of the `pl196x` module with that of some other module you have in mind. At first glance, it is not particularly limited though.